# Magento 2 admin loading very slow after redis configuration

Tags: magento, redis, magento2.4

I configured the redis on Magento 2.4.3. But after that my admin loading is very slow. When I debug then I found there in redis for session requests it is returning

> "HINCRBY" "sess_llm5difqva5dpp955o4ansht8h" "lock" "1"

with multiple request that's why it is taking time to load in admin panel. Did anyone face this issue, if yes then can you please share the solution? On google I found one link https://github.com/colinmollenhour/Cm_RedisSession/issues/92 but there is no solution for it.

Answer (score 0):

In your

```
app/etc/env.php
```

at `array session[redis][disable_locking]` is 0 (`'disable_locking' => '0'`,)

it should be  `'disable_locking' => '1'`